# Mathematica Fails to Solve a System of 3 Equations!

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve what I thought would be a simple set of 3 equations for Mathematica! But it grinds endlessly without any result..

```
sol = Solve[{1/a ==  1/(2 m c0) + x/Pi + 42 x^5 c2/(5 Pi c0), r == 2 R (1 - 
R/a) - 8 Pi x^3 c2/(3*c0), v == (R^2/3) (r + (R - 16 Pi x^3 c2/c0)) + c2/(c0^2 
m)}, {c0, c2, R}, Reals]
```

Comment: After I posted my answer, I ran your code without the `Reals` option.  I got a solution but  I don't know how long it took since I was away.  When I asked MMA to show the entire output,  the ram used by MMA ballooned to 20GB.  Yes that's a G.  It's a good thing my computer has 32GB.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've followed you suggestion and solved it one by one. Mathematica appreciated the help and cooperated this time!

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer, but the following code leads me to believe that this is not a *simple* set of equations.

```
r1 = First@Solve[1/a == 1/(2 m c0) + x/Pi + 42 x^5 c2/(5 Pi c0), c2]
r2 = First@Solve[r == 2. R (1 - R/a) - 8. Pi x^3 c2/(3*c0), c2]
r3 = First@Solve[(c2 /. r1) == (c2 /. r2), c0]
r4 = First@Solve[v == (R^2/3) (r + (R - 16. Pi x^3 c2/c0)) + c2/(c0^2 m) /. 
     r2 /. r3, R]
```

The above code does produce *R(a,x,r,v)* which can then be used to find expressions for c0 and c2, but it is (in my opinion at least) ugly and far from trivial.

Comment: you can simply use `Eliminate[{here system}, {c0, c2}]` which gives quartic equation on `R`. The solution is very complicated (especially if we add `Reals`). So, I think OP shold consider using `NSolve` after assigning values to `a, m, x, r, v`.

Answer (score 3):

The equations might be simple, but the solution is not so simple.  We can solve them one at a time.

```
eq1 = 1/a == 1/(2 m c0) + x/Pi + 42 x^5 c2/(5 Pi c0);

c2sol = Solve[eq1, c2] // Flatten // Simplify // Collect[#, c0] &

(*{c2 -> -((5 c0 (2 a m x - 2 π m))/(84 a m x^5)) - (5 π)/(84 m x^5)}*)
```

Put into a simpler form to make it easier to solve further.

```
c2 = aa + bb c0
```

Save the values of aa and bb for later.

```
aarule = aa -> -((5 π)/(84 m x^5));
bbrule = bb -> -((5 (2 a m x - 2 π m))/(84 a m x^5));
```

Now

```
eq2 = r == 2 R (1 - R/a) - 8 x^3 c2/(3*c0);
```

and solve for `c0`

```
c0sol = Solve[eq2, c0] // Flatten // Simplify
(*{c0 -> -((8 a aa x^3)/(8 a bb x^3 + 3 a r - 6 a R + 6 R^2))}*)
```

Simplify this one.

```
c0 = cc/(dd - 6 a R + 6 R^2)
```

And save for later.

```
ccrule = cc -> 8 a aa x^3
ddrule = dd -> 8 a bb x^3 + 3 a r
```

The final equation now depends only or R

```
eq3 = v == (R^2/3) (r + (1 - 2 x^3 c2/c0)) + c2/(c0^2 m);

Solve[eq3, R]
(* a very, very long output*)
```

Mathematica solves the final equation with multiple solutions for R. The solution comes rather quickly, but when I asked it to `Simplify` it took long enough for me to abort.  Substituting back the values of `aa,bb,cc,dd` will lengthen the solution even more.

I don't think adding the option `Reals` helps in this case.  All the unassigned variables in your equations makes it impossible to tell what is real.

Comment: after solving for eq3 for R, and putting in numerical values for things, I get an expression that contains R instead of a number. I'm not sure how to get a numerical answer. It says R->Root{{....expression that has R and #1..}}

Answer (score 2):

After making an intermediate replacement $c2\to \alpha\ c0$, `Solve` takes just a few seconds. And it returns 4 monstrous solutions.

```
eqsNew = {1/a == 1/(2 m c0) + x/Pi + 42 x^5 c2/(5 Pi c0), 
  r == 2 R (1 - R/a) - 8 Pi x^3 c2/(3*c0), 
  v == (R^2/3) (r + (R - 16 Pi x^3 c2/c0)) + c2/(c0^2 m)} /. c2 -> α c0;
sols = {c0, α c0, R} /. (solsNew = Solve[eqsNew, {c0, α, R}]);
Length[sols]
LeafCount /@ sols
```

> 4
>
> {626656, 626656, 626656, 626656}

Verifying using a random test case

```
Chop[Subtract @@@ eqsNew /. solsNew /. Thread[{a, m, r, v, x} -> RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {5}]]]
```

> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}

Comment: `c2` is not directly proportional to `c0` according to the first equation.

Comment: @BillWatts As far as I can see, $c2$ always appears as $\frac{c2}{c0}$. I essentially replaced the latter with $\alpha$.

Comment: And yet if you solve the first equation for `c2`, you do not get a `constant*c0`.

Comment: @BillWatts $\alpha$ is not a constant number but a function of the other parameters. I have now verified the answer with real values.

Comment: @BillWatts I looked at your answer. You choose to model $c2$ as $aa+bb\ c0$. I choose to model it as $\alpha\ c0$. $\alpha \neq bb$. My model presumes that the variables in $aa$ can be reorganized as $something\ c0$.

Comment: I agree you can assign anything you want.  When I do that, however, I get a set of equations just as complicated as before with $\alpha$ substituted for $c2$.  I guess either way works.  Regardless, this problem is much more easily solved with numbers rather than with variables.

Comment: @BillWatts Agreed. It is better to use some numbers as the resulting solutions are very unwieldy and not suitable to probe for any insights, etc.